# In which case I need ampersand in pointers?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, implicit-conversion, addressof

I am trying to understand pointer to pointers and I can not understand why in first case I need (&) ampersand ( I receive a message [Error] cannot convert 'char*' to 'char**' in assignment )
and in the second case I don't need ampersand

first case :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>


int main ()
{
    
    char *p ={"jack is a good boy"};
    
    char**p1;
    
    p1=p; //why I need & in this case
    
    return0;
}
```

second case :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>


int main ()
{
    
    char *p[5] ={"jack","is", "a","good","boy"};
    
    int i=0;
    
    char**p1;
    
    p1=p;
    
    //p1=&p[0];
    
    for(p1=p; *p1; p1++)
    {
        
        
        printf("\n the words are %s",*p1);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> p1=p; //why I need & in this case

The variable `p` has the type `char *`

```
char *p ={"jack is a good boy"};
```

While the variable `p1` has the type `char **`

```
char**p1;
```

So you are trying to use incompatible pointer types in the assignment statement.

You need to write

```
p1 = &p;
```

In this case the pointer `p1` will point to the object `p` that has the type `char *`. That is a pointer to the object `p` will have the type `char **`.

In the second program you declared an array with the element type `char *`.

```
char *p[5] ={"jack","is", "a","good","boy"};
```

Array designator used in expressions with rare exception is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element

So in this assignment statement

```
p1=p;
```

that is equivalent to

```
p1 = &p[0];
```

the expression `p` used as an initializer is converted to the type `char **`. So the left and the right operands of the assignment have the same pointer type.

Pay attention to that this for loop

```
for(p1=p; *p1; p1++)
{
    
    
    printf("\n the words are %s",*p1);
}
```

invokes undefined behavior because the array `p`  does not have a null pointer among its elements. Thus the condition of the for loop `*p1` that is the same as `*p1 != NULL` will not be evaluated for elements of the array `p`.

If the loop will be correct you need to include an element that is equal to null pointer, For example

```
char *p[6] ={"jack","is", "a","good","boy"};
       ^^^
```

or

```
char *p[] = {"jack","is", "a","good","boy", NULL };
```

Comment: @ Vlad from Moscow 
Ok  so when I want to declare an array of pointers with k pointers I have to increase the numberof lements to k+1 but why when I ran this program with 5 elements and not 6 I did not have a warning from dev?

Comment: @vgag1997 There is no need to do that. If you know the exact number of elements in an array you can use a for loop that uses for example the condition i < k or i != k. If you rely on a sentinel value of an array of pointers then you can use a null pointer as a sentinel value.

Answer (score 0):

The unary `&` operator could be seen as a *pointer-to* operator.

From the first example, `p` is a pointer to `char` and `p1` is a pointer to a pointer to a `char`. But when you have `&p` it becomes a pointer to a pointer to a `char`, of the type `char **`, which makes is the same type as `p1`.

In the second example, `p` is an array of pointers. And as all arrays it can *decay* to a pointer to its first element. So just using `p` alone is the same as `&p[0]`. And as `p[0]` is a pointer to `char` (i.e. `char *`) then `&p[0]` is a pointer to a pointer to `char` (i.e. `char **`).

So in the first example the pointer-to operator must be used to get a pointer to a pointer to `char`. This isn't needed in the second example because the pointer-to operator is used implicitly.